# How to implement nc commands in python?

Tags: python-3.x, netcat

I'm very new to development and may I know the equivalent python script for the following net cat command.

```
nc -v localhost 11211
```

#UPDATE

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect(('localhost', 11211))
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print(s.sendall(data.encode('get STATUS_MANAGER_KEYS')))    
except:
    print('error')
finally:
    s.close()
```

Changed it as above but it showing an infinite execution at line `data = s.recv(1024)`. May I know how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look into socket programming. Here's an example I found online https://steelkiwi.com/blog/working-tcp-sockets/

As you can see all netcat does is create a tcp connection to the network address and the port. It binds to it.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost', 11211))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

You may also want to checkout this wikipedia on Network Sockets https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket

Comment: Need to check this also `get STATUS_MANAGER_KEYS`. Could help for that

Comment: `import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 50000))
s.sendall('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)`

Comment: I was able to connect to server but how can I run `get STATUS_MANAGER_KEYS`

Comment: When I add it in s.sendall('get STATUS_MANAGER_KEYS'), I got f/w error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netcater.py", line 4, in <module>
    s.sendall('STATUS_MANAGER_KEYS')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Hi @Ark, try to encode the data first. as an example do data.encode() on the second to last line. so it would look like so


    `conn.sendall(data.encode())`

We do this the underlying protocols are likely based on sending ascii rather than unicode.

Comment: data.encode('get STATUS_MANAGER_KEYS') , is this your suggestion

Comment: Can't hurt to try.

Comment: I have tried it as you suggested but am getting an infinite execution. Could you please help me to understand what is missing in that. I have modified the code and have look on it